# Is this an acceptable approach to decrease within-sample variance before comparing between sample variance

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a data set which contains two samples and my main objective is to check if they are statistically significantly different.

In my case:

Every image contains 4 dots. In this example D1 is the lowest and D4 the highest for each image. Although we are not interested in comparing the dots (so no need to go into two factor anova or a nested model), the argument is, by grouping the dots together for each image, we can decrease the overall variance, thus our t-test of S1 vs S2 will be more reliable.

In this scenario, would grouping be beneficial? As Peter mentioned below, the hypothesis is not the same when the data is not grouped vs grouped.

Original data

[image]

Grouped data by taking means of dots for each image

[image]

Questions:

1) What hypothesis am I testing when I have grouped my data and use a t-test

2) Is this a valid approach? if not why?

3) What is the impact of the t-test (or any other general test) when grouping the data?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think this is a legitimate thing to do; at the least, it's not a test of the same hypothesis.

Second, while your example is obviously a toy example, let's see what happens. (Below is R code, anything after a # is a comment)

```
s1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
s2 <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)

t.test(s1,s2)  #t = -4.38, df = 6, p = 0.0047

s3 <- c(1.5, 3.5)
s4 <- c(5.5, 7.5)

t.test(s3,s4) # t = -2.82, df - 2, p = 0.11
```

So, not only is it sort of a suspicious method, it doesn't really do what you want it to.

If you have two independent variables (sample and group) then I think the way to go is regression, but doing that on this data set won't work because each group has only one observation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm actually trying to justify to a colleague why this is not a suitable approach. As you noted, this is of course a toy example but can you think of any case where this grouping can be more beneficial? I'd like to make a solid argument as to why this isn't the way forward.

Comment: The argument for grouping these variables together is by not grouping, we are increasing the variance as the `x` values in the first data table have unique characteristics and we don't want them to play a role as we are interested in the overall groups value.

Comment: Well, sure, grouping could sometimes be very useful. Usually, like I said, this would call for regression with the group as an independent variable. But you might want to group and then do two different t-tests - one on each group.

Comment: I see, i've added in context to my question and I hope it will clarify the structure of the data i'm working with. Also in terms of regression, i'm only interested in knowing if there is a difference between samples, not to inference for groups. Is regression still preferable?